# combinar matrices de imagenes en las que se uso diferente filtro matlab

Tags: matlab

Tenía un problema con una imagen, en la binarización al aumentar el umbral una zona ganaba definición mientras otra ganaba ruido y así sucesivamente; por lo que separé lo que necesita umbral más grande así:

```
I=imread('img.jpg') 

I2=imcrop(I;[coordenadas])

Bin1=binarización I1(umbral l);

Bin2=binarización i2(umbral l+1);
```

ahora mi duda es:

**¿Cómo reemplazar la Bin2(imagen chica) en Bin1(imagen grande)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo mencionas, la idea es sustituir una región de la *imagen grande* que ha sido filtrada utilizando un umbral diferente, así pues, lo único que necesitas es hacer una sustitución de elementos de una matriz, para ello usas la indexación:

```
Matriz(i1:i2, j1:j2) = matriz_reemplazo
```

Donde `matriz_reemplazo` será una matriz de dimensiones **(i2-i1)x(j2-j1)**, es decir, de las mismas dimensiones que la submatriz que estás refiriendo con la indexación.

Para dejar más claro lo anterior, un ejemplo:

```
IG = imread('cameraman.tif');
I2 = imcrop(IG,[50 50 100 100]);
BWG = im2bw(IG, 0.3);
BW2 = im2bw(I2, 0.6);
% Sin sustituir la región recortada
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(BWG);
% Sustituyendo la región recortada
subplot(1,2,2);
BWG(50:150,50:150) = BW2;
imshow(BWG);
```

Que produce las siguientes imágenes:

*Sin sustituir la región recortada*
[image: Antes de añadir el recorte]

*Sustituyendo la región recortada*
[image: Después de añadir el recorte]

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta :)